# Is $f(x)=x^{3}+3x^{2}+12x-2\sin x $ one-one and onto?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For linear or simple quadratic equations, it is quite simple to check if the function is onto or not. But I often face questions like the one I posted above, to check whether they are one-one and onto. While ascertaining that it is one-one is a piece of cake (using first derivative) is there an algorithm to ascertain whether it is onto or into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's continuous, the limit at $-\infty$ is $-\infty$, and the limit at $\infty$ is $\infty$, so it must be onto.

Answer (score 3):

$$f'(x)=3x^2+6x+12-2\cos(x)$$

It's not complicated to show that $3x^2+6x+12\geq 3$ for all $x$ and thus that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$. Therefore, $f$ is strictly increasing and therefore one-to-one. For the onto part, see **hunter** answer.

Answer (score 1):

Find $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$. If one limit equals $\infty$ and the other equals $-\infty$, than the image of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that $f$ is onto.